# How do I find out whats closing my port?

Tags: windows, port

On a Windows Server 2016 Standard, 64-bit, x64-based server, I try to connect to a specific port (1807) to access a third party application using Eclipse. However, an as yet unidentified process is closing it.

How do I find out what?

There seems to be lots of info about how to close ports on SO, but can't find anything about how to monitor what  is closing it.

According to a co-worker who looks after the firewall the port is open. Although I also tried running Eclipse on the server and connection to the port inside the firewall. Tried connecting via a testing tool and get "The underlying connection was closed. The connection was closed unexpectedly."

The message connecting via Eclipse is "Cannot join host http://myHost:1807 - Possible reasons could be the host is temporarily unavailable, DNS cannot resolve this name. The port is not open to the outside. The host name is mispelt. The host response has timed out. The host has multiple network cards but one of them is not responding. The newtwork infrastructure does not allow the access to this host".

Eclipse connects via another port OK.

Please let me know if you have any ideas about how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the PID of port closing program by `netstat -a -n -o`. Then by using

`tasklist /fi "pid eq 6368"` you can find the name of program. `6368` is the pid of program that's blocking the port

Comment: Thanks @alynurly, I can see two processes when running netstat -b -n -o | find "1807"TCP    123.456.7.89:1807      123.456.7.89:50226     ESTABLISHED     4352
  TCP    123.456.7.89:50226     123.456.7.89:1807      ESTABLISHED     8112

Comment: tried tasklist /fi "pid eq 50226" but get INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.

Comment: pid is usually 4 characters. In your case 4352 and 8112